# ASP.NET Core missing references glitch in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.Net Core but I'm getting weird missing reference squiggles even though the project compiles and the code is working.  I've tried to clean the solution and rebuild but this error will not disappear. 
[image]

Is there any trick to getting Visual Studio 17 to stop doing this?

Comment: Does it build? (if not, what are the errors) Are you using Resharper?

Comment: If there are some dependencies that need to be updated, update them and if some of them are not loaded properly when opening the project, reopen it. If it compiles alright then you don't have a problem. Also as @Julian mentioned, sometimes Resharper is guilty for this kind of behavior.

Comment: Not using ReSharper and yes it builds.

Comment: I should have also said I updated all the references via nuget so everything compiles just fine.

Comment: I got same kind of error for " app.UseBrowserLink();". For that i deleted my bin folder and rebuild my project, after that it worked fine. Can you give this a try?

Comment: deleting the bin worked.   If you put that as a answer I will accept it.